# How to extract substring in R

Tags: r, string

I have a string like the below

```
x <- "Supplier will initially respond to High Priority incidents.  Supplier will subsequently update EY every 60 minutes or at an interval EY specifies. Reporting and Response times will be capture in ServiceNow which, save in respect of manifest error, will be conclusive proof of the time period taken."
```

I want to extract 2 words after the word "every".

How this can be achieved in R?

Comment: It's probably because you shown 0-effort and ask a question `give me some code`. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` by using a regex workaround (`(?<=every\\s)`) followed by two words

```
library(stringr) #corrected the package here
unlist(str_extract_all(x, "(?<=every\\s)(\\w+\\s+\\w+)"))
#[1] "60 minutes"
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<=every\\s)(\\w+\\s+\\w+)", x, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
#[1] "60 minutes"
```

Comment: akrun, the correct package is `stringr` not `stringi`

Comment: @akrun - thanks for the response. Could you please let me know how to change the unlist command in stringr so that the output is "every 30 seconds"

Comment: try this `paste("every",unlist(str_extract_all(x, "(?<=every\\s)(\\w+\\s+\\w+)")),sep = " ") `

Comment: @Arun You can remove the regex lookaround and it should work `unlist(str_extract_all(x, "every\\s\\w+\\s+\\w+"))
#[1] "every 60 minutes"`

Comment: @Arun: See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A good idea is to pay attention at [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in base R,

Splitting every word of the string and then finding the index of occurrence of word `every` and then selecting next two words from that index.

```
wordsplit <- unlist(strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE))
indx <- grep("\\bevery\\b", wordsplit)
wordsplit[(indx+1):(indx +2)]
#[1] "60"      "minutes"
```

Or as @DavidArenburg suggested we can also use `match` instead of `grep`

```
 wordsplit[match("every", wordsplit) + 1:2]
```